# show that $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5} -2\sin x}$, is bounded on the interval $0\leq x \leq 2\pi$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

show that $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5} -2\sin x}$,  is bounded on the interval $0\leq x \leq 2\pi$.
How do I prove that the functon is bounded? Do I first prove that it is an increasing or decreasing function and then find the $\lim\to2\pi$, or do I just have to find the domain of the derivative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: show that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}-2\sin(x)}\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}-2}$$
for all $x$ with $0\le x\le 2\pi$

Comment: basically all i have to show is 2sin(x) is always less than 2.

Comment: but where di you get 1/(sqrt5 - 2)? thats the max of the original function, i would have to find the max when the derivative equals zero, i can't just pull that number out of nowhere right?

Comment: since $\sqrt{5}-2 \le \sqrt{5}-2\sin(x)$